# Resolve alias' original item using bookmarkData

Tags: strings, url

This is my first Objective-C++ code, so I'm a bit lacking in the knowledge of methods.

I need to resolve a macOS alias and get its original location. I have access to the C string, which is the file path (in a human readable form). It also needs to be verified in this code itself that it is a true alias, and contains bookmark data.

```
const char *class::resolveAliasFromURL(const char *filepath) const{

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    char filepath[] = "/Users/me/alias"; /*you need to make an alias here*/
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:filepath];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:string]; 
    NSData *bmdata = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (!error) { /*needs better error catching*/
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"URL: %@",url); // Useless; sanity check 
    }

    error = nil;
    BOOL isstale = NO;
    BOOL *isStalePointer = &isstale;
    char ref[] = "";
    NSString *relString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ref];
    NSURL *relativeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:relString];
    NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions option = NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI;
    NSURL *actual = [[NSURL alloc]
        initByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmarkData
                            options:option
                      relativeToURL:relativeURL
                bookmarkDataIsStale:isStalePointer
                              error:&error]; /*resolved NSURL object file://<some numbers>*/

    char resolved[100]; /*resolved path in C; need to get length of the string, not arbitrarily 100 */
    strcpy(resolved, [actual fileSystemRepresentation]);
    printf(" %s\n",resolved);

    /*Need to check if the resolved object is a file or a directory*/

    [pool drain];
    return tempPath;
}
```

[`bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408344-bookmarkdatawithcontentsofurl?language=objc):

```
+ (NSData *)bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)bookmarkFileURL 
                                    error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

[`initByResolvingBookmarkData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1413475-initbyresolvingbookmarkdata)

```
- (instancetype)initByResolvingBookmarkData:(NSData *)bookmarkData 
                                    options:(NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions)options 
                              relativeToURL:(NSURL *)relativeURL 
                        bookmarkDataIsStale:(BOOL *)isStale 
                                      error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

- Is there some improvements I can make given the goal and constraints?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103675/discussion-on-question-by-ankk-resolve-alias-original-item-using-bookmarkdata).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Memory management

The use of `NSAutoreleasePool` makes it apparent that this code is compiled  *manual reference counting.* That is error-prone, as you'll see now: Here

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:filepath];
NSString *relString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:ref];
NSURL *actual = [[NSURL alloc] initByResolvingBookmarkData ...];
```

are objects allocated but never released. That makes several memory leaks on each invocation of the method.

The easiest fix would be to use *automatic reference counting (ARC)* instead. ARC is available since Mac OS 10.6, and there is no reason not to use it. You only have to adjust the compiler flags (i.e. do *not* pass `-fno-objc-arc` to the compiler) and replace (compare [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsautoreleasepool))

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// ...
[pool drain];
```

by

```
@autoreleasepool {
    // ...
}
```

The compiler takes care of everything else and inserts `retain` and `release` calls where appropriate.

If – for whatever reason – switching to ARC is not feasible then you have to fix the above-mentioned issues. You can add the needed release calls, e.g.

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:filepath];
// ...
[string release];
```

or (perhaps simpler) create autoreleased objects (which are released on return of the function, when the autorelease pool is drained):

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:filepath];
NSURL *actual = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData ...];
```

`string` can also more simply be created as a [“boxed C string”](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#boxed-c-strings):

```
NSString *string = @(filepath);
```

Another error is here:

```
char resolved[100]; /*resolved path in C; need to get length of the string, not arbitrarily 100 */
strcpy(resolved, [actual fileSystemRepresentation]);
// ...
return tempPath;
```

because the function returns the address of a *local* variable, which is undefined behavior.

You can make the character buffer static: That seems to be what similar functions in the blender project do. The disadvantage is that subsequent calls to the function overwrite the buffer.

Or you can allocate a new string, and the caller has to release the memory eventually.

#### Error handling

The correct way to check for success or failure of Cocoa (Touch) methods is 
documented in
["Handling Error Objects Returned From Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-SW1) in the "Error Handling Programming Guide":

> **Important:** Success or failure is indicated by the return value of the
>   method. Although Cocoa methods that indirectly return error objects in
>   the Cocoa error domain are guaranteed to return such objects if the
>   method indicates failure by directly returning nil or NO, you should
>   always check that the return value is nil or NO before attempting to
>   do anything with the NSError object.

In your case, the correct way to check for the success of

```
NSData *bmdata = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

would be

```
if (bmdata == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}
```

But `NSLog()`ing the error is not sufficient: You have to report the failure to the caller, e.g. by returning a `nullptr`:

```
if (bmdata == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading bookmark data for %@: %@",url, error);
    [pool drain];
    return nullptr;
}
```

Note that (if you keep the manual reference counting) you must take care that the autorelease pool is drained on any return from the function.

The same error handling must be done when resolving the bookmark data, that is missing completely.

#### More remarks

- `relString` and `relativeURL` are not needed, you can simply pass `nil` to the `relativeToURL` argument.
- `isStalePointer` is not needed, you can pass `&isstale` directly to the `bookmarkDataIsStale` argument. Or pass `nil` is you are not interested in the outcome (at present, the staleness is not evaluated in your code).

#### File system paths conversions

The conversion from an `NSURL` back to a C string with

```
char resolved[100];
strcpy(resolved, [actual fileSystemRepresentation]);
```

suggests that the C strings represent “file system paths” and in that case the correct counterpart for the conversion from the given `filepath` to an `NSURL` is

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation:filepath
                                            isDirectory:NO
                                          relativeToURL:nil];
```

But a buffer with 100 characters may be too short: Either determine the needed length dynamically, or use `MAXPATHLEN` from the system include files. Also `strcpy` does not check if the target buffer is large enough (potentially causing a memory corruption). Better use

```
static char resolved[MAXPATHLEN];
if (![actual getFileSystemRepresentation:resolved maxLength:sizeof(resolved)]) {
    NSLog(@"File system path too long for %@", url);
    [pool drain];
    return nullptr;
}
```

#### Putting it together

Putting all the above suggestions together, the code (with manual reference counting) would be

```
const char *YourClass::resolveAlias(const char *filepath) const {

    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation:filepath
                                                isDirectory:NO
                                              relativeToURL:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *bmdata = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (bmdata == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading bookmark data for %@: %@",url, error);
        [pool drain];
        return nullptr;
    }
    NSURL *actual = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bmdata
                                              options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI
                                        relativeToURL:nil
                                  bookmarkDataIsStale:nil
                                                error:&error];
    if (actual == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error resolving bookmark data for %@: %@", url, error);
        [pool drain];
        return nullptr;
    }

    static char resolved[MAXPATHLEN];
    if (![actual getFileSystemRepresentation:resolved maxLength:sizeof(resolved)]) {
        NSLog(@"File system path too long for %@", url);
        [pool drain];
        return nullptr;
    }

    [pool drain];
    return resolved;
}
```

#### Further simplification

As of macOS 10.10 the `NSURL` class has a

```
+ (instancetype)URLByResolvingAliasFileAtURL:(NSURL *)url 
                                     options:(NSURLBookmarkResolutionOptions)options 
                                       error:(NSError * _Nullable *)error;
```

initializer, which both reads and resolves the bookmark data. The function then simplifies to (now with automatic reference counting):

```
const char *YourClass::resolveAlias(const char *filepath) const {
    static char resolved[MAXPATHLEN];
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithFileSystemRepresentation:filepath
                                                    isDirectory:NO
                                                  relativeToURL:nil];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *resolvedURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingAliasFileAtURL:url
                                                      options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI
                                                        error:&error];
        if (![resolvedURL getFileSystemRepresentation:resolved maxLength:sizeof(resolved)]) {
            NSLog(@"File system path too long for %@", url);
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    return resolved;
}
```

Comment: I think we're going to keep it `void` and pass two pointers into it.. fits better with  error catching and the rest of the code. Thanks for such an amazing review!  https://nopaste.xyz/?850b0ee6b68d56f1#JpZYNesyRtC6Q7IHjvdu67hLl58TZ/G01X3DVP/4HqM= Will fix some little bits after integration

Comment: @ankk: Good idea, but better pass a destination pointer *and* the destination buffer size to the function. Also the function then should return a boolean to indicate success or failure.